# Intellij 14 won't compile with res/transition folder that was added in Android 5.0 (?)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Any idea how to fix this error? From the [transition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html) API reference it says that all of your transitions must be in the res/transition folder which I believe was added in Android 5.0, but I could be mistaken. I created a "transition" folder under the res directory in Intellij 14 and it seemed okay, let me set transitionSet as the root and what not, recognized it as a thing that exists in Android, but when I try to compile I get this error:

```
Error: android-apt-controller:[MyApp] invalid resource directory name: /filepath
```

Any ideas? I am very new to Android and am trying to set a button to have an Explode transition effect when the visibility is set to VISIBLE.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not something as banal as forward slash vs. backslash?

Comment: checked, this is not the issue. thanks for the response!